# Nested JSON NSJSONseralization

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I am struggling with the following problem:

I've got an API which returns a nested JSON piece.
(I use NSJSONSeralization to parse it)

eg:

```
 { "thing" = 1,
   "Other thing" = 2,
   "ParentFromList": [{
   "IT" = 3,
   "SecondIT" = 4
 }
```

How can I use IT and Second it?

I've tried:

```
  NSDictionary *thingy = [[jsonOutput objectForKey:@"ParentFromList"] ObjectForKey:@"IT"];
```

JsonOutput is also a nsdictionary.
But after running it, it fails with:

```
  Unrecognized Selector send to instance.
```

I don't know how to fix this, help appreciated.

Comment: Just remember that {} means a dictionary and [] means its a array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your data, the outmost object is a `NSDictionary` instance. The value for the key *ParentFromList* is an array, i.e. a `NSArray`instance (note the brackets). The arrays first element contains another dictionary instance (note the curly braces).

Furthermore, it's not `ObjectForKey:` but `objectForKey:` (case matters).

So you probably want to write:

```
NSDictionary *thingy = [ [ [jsonOutput objectForKey: @"ParentFromList"]
                         objectAtIndex: 0]
                       objectForKey: @"IT"];
```

BTW: Your sample JSON data is both incomplete and not in JSON format (it's Apple's property list format).

The correct and complete JSON representation would be:

```
{
    "thing": 1,
    "Other thing": 2,
    "ParentFromList": [
        {
            "IT": 3,
            "SecondIT": 4
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Also the JSON part was just for explanation